# Play audio and video at the same time in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video

Hi I'm  trying to play two different files at the same time.

I tried to create several players using `AVFoundation` and `MediaPlayer`, but it doesn't work well.  What's the best way to play audio file and video at the same time?

The reason I'm taking separate files is to save space, because the app will be localized, having only 26 audio files for each language instead of having 26 videos saves space. That's important because apple doesn't allow the download of app size above 100 MB.

Comment: The 100 MB limit is only over cell networks. Over WiFi the download limit is 2 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `AVAudioPlayer` in combination with `MPMoviePlayerController`

For the `AVAudioPlayer`, you set it to an ambient session, this will allow for another media source to play simultaneously. I have posted some code below. This is pulled from a side project I did that can be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/MZimmerman6/FireplaceReceiver)

```
AVAudioPlayer audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie"
                                                   ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[[moviePlayer view] setFrame:someFrame];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
[moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[moviePlayer play];
```

If you want this to be changeable, you just load in a different audio URL to the same audio player and you should be good to go.

Comment: no problem at all. I had quite some trouble with this as well initially until I found a tutorial online about it, but do not recall where that was now.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I want to custom a Video Player using AVFoundation, it ís OK ?

Comment: @HoanNguyen I am not sure what you mean. You want to create a custom video player? How do you want to customize it?

Comment: Sorry, about the comment, i mean i want to play video & audio file at the same time, but  dont use MPMoviePlayerVC, maybe i custom video player, using AVfoundation. Does it work?

Comment: @HoanNguyen I do not know, I have not tried to do that. Try it, google around a bit. if you continue to have problems, post a question on here detailing what you attempted, what your error is, and post some associated code.