# Apple TV overlay audio of video

Tags: ios, tvos

I want to build an `Apple TV` app that plays a list of short **videos** and **plays music** over them.

To achieve this I need to do two following things:

**1)** Mute the `videos` or remove the `audio tracks` from them

I have no Idea if/how this is possible. I looked around the TVJS documentation for [Player](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/Player) and [MediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/MediaItem) but found nothing.

**2)** Play **two** `media items` at the same time.

From [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/Player/play) I already know that this is at least not possible with two players. I also tried to use the background audio of my `TVML Template` but this didn't work either.

Does anyone know of a way how something like this would be possible?

**Edit (some more information):**

For testing stuff I used the code from [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial)

At the suggesion of Daniel Storm I tried to change the `load` function in `Presenter.js` to both

```
load: function(event) {
  var self = this,
  ele = event.target,
  videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL")
  if(videoURL) {
    var player = new Player();
    var playlist = new Playlist();
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

    player.playlist = playlist;
    player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
    mediaItem.volume = 0.0;

    player.present();
  }
},
```

and

```
load: function(event) {
  var self = this,
  ele = event.target,
  videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL")
  if(videoURL) {
    var player = new Player();
    var playlist = new Playlist();
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

    player.playlist = playlist;
    player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
    player.volume = 0.0;

    player.present();
  }
},
```

but neither worked.

Comment: This question is too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: For point one I tried nothing because I didn't find anything in the documentation.

For point two I tried adding a background audio to my TVML Template as is described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/CompoundBackgroundElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH24-SW3
But its stops playing when I start the Player

Comment: Pretty sure something like `someVideo.volume = 0.0` would work.

Comment: Most likely, you have to use Swift or Objective-C. With `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)` your audio should mix with the video audio, which you can mute. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952309/play-audio-and-video-at-the-same-time-in-ios.

Comment: @Codo I'm not sure how that would work since selecting and playing the video is done in TVJS and TVML